# Get values of Bootstrap-select options using jquery

Tags: jquery, select, mousehover

I write this Html and use Bootstrap-select to create jquery select

```
<select id="type" class="selectpicker">
        <option>Select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

how can I check mouseover or hover event with jquery ? I want to alert the value of  options.

Bootstrap-select creates select box
SelectBox is constructed in the following manner:

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner "><li class="selected active"><a role="option"

 aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" class="selected active" aria-selected="true">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span><span 

class="text">Select...</span></a></li><li><a role="option" aria-disabled="false" 

tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-

mark"></span><span class="text">1</span></a></li><li><a role="option" aria-

disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class="glyphicon 

glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span><span class="text">2</span></a></li></ul>
```

solved this in the following manner

```
    $('.bootstrap-select').on('mouseover', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target.children);
        if ($target.is('span')) {
            console.log($target.text());
        }
```

Comment: What is "Bootstrap-select"?

Comment: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#bootstrap-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<select>` gets wrapped in a container with class `bootstrap-select` so after you initialize plugin you can do:

```
  $('.bootstrap-select').on('mouseenter', function(e){
     console.log($(this).find('select').val())
  })
```

Or you could delegate the listener before initializing plugin

```
  $(document).on('mouseenter','.bootstrap-select', function(e){
     console.log($(this).find('select').val())
  })
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/983cozkg/)**</kbd>

Comment: This solution only shows initial value when I mouse enter the select. But Then When I press it, and start to move through options nothing happens.

That's because you use mouseenter. And I understand this. I changed it to mouseover, and now I get a lot of logs while moving through options.

Problem is that I do not get the correct values because this select is constructed   
in a complicated way I will update my question for that.

Comment: Solved myself and updated the question with solution. Marking your answer as solution by the way. You showed the right path. Thanks!